DataSet encoding of map and sequence of LocalDate problems
I'm writing a solution in Scala based on Spark 3.5.0 that has complex map/seq data structures of dates where I need to represent missing dates with null or None. As this is scala my preference is None, however, I get an exception trying to encode Option[LocalDate] in a sequence or map. As a workaround, I switched to Null but I can't do this in a map as Null can't be used as a key.
This is code that reproduces the problem:
case class SubClass[T](i: Option[T])

case class TestClass[T](i: Option[T] = None, st: Option[SubClass[T]], sq: Option[Seq[Option[T]]] = None)

  it should "handle sequence of date" in {
    val sparkSession = spark
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val aDate = LocalDate.parse("2024-04-29")
    
    var ds = Seq(TestClass[LocalDate](Some(aDate), Some(SubClass[LocalDate](Some(aDate))), Some(Seq(Some(aDate))))).toDS    
    
    ds.show
  }

  it should "handle date structure" in {
    val sparkSession = spark
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val aDate = LocalDate.parse("2024-04-29")
    
    var ds = Seq(TestClass[LocalDate](Some(aDate), Some(SubClass[LocalDate](Some(aDate))))).toDS    
    
    ds.show
  }


  it should "handle sequence of double" in {
    val sparkSession = spark
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val aNum = 2.42
    
    var ds = Seq(TestClass[Double](Some(aNum), Some(SubClass[Double](Some(aNum))), Some(Seq(Some(aNum))))).toDS    
    
    ds.show
  }

  it should "handle sequence of string" in {
    val sparkSession = spark
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val aString = "Foo"
    
    var ds = Seq(TestClass[String](Some(aString), Some(SubClass[String](Some(aString))), Some(Seq(Some(aString))))).toDS    
    
    ds.show
  }

For the above tests, they all work except should handle sequence of date which fails with exception org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Some is not a valid external type for schema of date.
This only seems to be an issue with LocalDate as the Double and String tests work just fine.
Can anyone suggest a workaround or fix for this?
Thanks,
David

I assume this is 3.5.0, on that version I can reproduce, but on 3.5.1 it no longer occurs.
Probably this is triggered by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-45896
(the fix is present on Databricks 14.3 LTS but not on lower versions)

Chris, thank you for the quick response. I hadn't tested on Databricks because 14.3 LTS says that its using Spark 3.5.0 but I've now tested there and, as you say, it does work. I've also updated my sbt poroject to use Spark 3.5.1 and it works with my unit tests.
